# Conditional formatting on a calculation in excel

Tags: excel

I have a performance tracker consisting of 3 rows, eg E3 is budget, E4 is actual, E5 is variance. I want the variance to automatically calculate, but only once I put the actual figure in. At the moment, if I run the calculation, it puts the budget figure in the variance cell because the actual cell is empty.

I want to apply the formula to the chart with the budgets in place, but not have a figure displayed in the variance box until I input the actual.

Comment: So use an if() to control whether variance is calculated : if(E4="","",variance_calculation).

Comment: Thank you, this has worked exactly how i wanted it to

Answer (score 0):

In E5, you could use`=IF(COUNTBLANK(E3:E4)=0,E3-E4,"")` which would provide a blank result if either of the two above values are missing.

However, if E3 or E4 are formulas that may result in an empty value, then I'd evaluate the result of each cell to determine if either were blank: `=IF(AND(E3<>"",E4<>""),E3-E4,"")`.

Hope this helps.